# Update DataTable based on Group By using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable

I have two datatable with same identity column. I want to update one column value in one table with other column value in another table. For example:

These are the two tables:

Table1:

```
   ID         Name          PaidAmount
 ------      -------        ---------
    1          AA             0
    2          BB             0
    3          CC             0
```

Table2:

```
   ID        Amount
 ------    ---------
    1        5000
    2        6000
    3        7000
    1        2000
```

My desired datatable should be like this:

DesiredTable:

```
   ID         Name          PaidAmount
 ------      -------        ---------
    1          AA             7000
    2          BB             6000
    3          CC             7000
```

Normally, in SQL SERVER to update, we use the following query

```
  UPDATE
     T1
  SET
     T1.PaidAmount = T2.Amount
  FROM
     Table1 T1
     INNER JOIN
     (
       SELECT SUM(Amount) AS Amount, ID FROM Table2 GROUP BY ID
     )    T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```

But, How to achieve this result using LINQ?

Comment: Are you using Linq to SQl or Linq to Entities??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, you have to perform two major operations:

1. Aggreate the data in `Table2`
2. Update the amount in `Table1`

For aggregation:

```
var aggregatedData = db.Table2
    .GroupBy(x => x.ID)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Id = g.Key,
        Amount = g.Sum(x => x.Amount)
    });
```

For update:

```
var joined = aggregatedData.Join(db.Table1,
        aggregatedItem => aggregatedItem.Id,
        x => x.ID,
        (aggregated, item) => new
        {
            Item = item,
            Data = aggregated
        });
foreach(var item in joined)
{
    item.Item.PaidAmount = item.Data.Amount;
}
```

Save the data:

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this and it is working perfectly for me.

I have Implemented this solution by considering **LINQ to Entities**

Please try following code:

```
 var result = from t1 in db.Table1
                     let t2 = from q in db.Table2
                              group q by q.ID into g
                              select new
                              {
                                  ID = g.Min(i => i.ID),
                                  Amount = g.Sum(i => i.Amount)
                              }
                     select new
                     {
                         t1.ID,
                         t1.Name,
                         PaidAmount = t2.Where(s => s.ID == t1.ID).FirstOrDefault().Amount,

                     };

        foreach (var res in result.ToList())
        {
            Table1 t = (from t1 in db.Table1
                        where t1.ID == res.ID
                        select t1).Single();
            t.PaidAmount = res.PaidAmount;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```